# Loss of Internet while on VPN on Mac

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, mac, vpn, routing

I have to connect to Cisco AnyConnect VPN from my Mac for work. Whenever I do, I lose the Internet.

My routing table before connecting;

```
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            10.0.2.1           UGSc           26        0     en0
10.0.2/24          link#4             UCS             5        0     en0
10.0.2.1/32        link#4             UCS             1        0     en0
10.0.2.1           64:a5:c3:61:2a:ba  UHLWIir        33      486     en0   1146
10.0.2.2           d0:7e:35:d4:ef:68  UHLWI           0        9     en0   1200
10.0.2.4           c4:b3:1:c9:7f:89   UHLWI           0        0     en0    782
10.0.2.10          18:65:90:cf:15:17  UHLWI           0        0     en0   1164
10.0.2.14          f4:5c:89:94:c7:45  UHLWI           0        0     en0    347
10.0.2.17          e0:94:67:2d:81:2e  UHLWI           0       40     en0   1146
10.0.2.26/32       link#4             UCS             0        0     en0
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH              1    36418     lo0
224.0.0/4          link#4             UmCS            2        0     en0
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI          0        0     en0
239.255.255.250    1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa    UHmLWI          0       82     en0
255.255.255.255/32 link#4             UCS             0        0     en0

Internet6:
Destination                             Gateway                         Flags         Netif Expire
default                                 fe80::%utun0                    UGcI          utun0
::1                                     ::1                             UHL             lo0
fe80::%lo0/64                           fe80::1%lo0                     UcI             lo0
fe80::1%lo0                             link#1                          UHLI            lo0
fe80::%en0/64                           link#4                          UCI             en0
fe80::1411:5e1:f2bf:a3ec%en0            18:65:90:d0:6a:11               UHLI            lo0
fe80::%awdl0/64                         link#8                          UCSI          awdl0
fe80::207a:82ff:febb:4907%awdl0         22:7a:82:bb:49:7                UHLI            lo0
fe80::50c8:6fe8:9656:1a31%utun0         link#10                         UHLI            lo0
ff01::%lo0/32                           ::1                             UmCI            lo0
ff01::%en0/32                           link#4                          UmCI            en0
ff01::%awdl0/32                         link#8                          UmCSI         awdl0
ff02::%lo0/32                           ::1                             UmCI            lo0
ff02::%en0/32                           link#4                          UmCI            en0
ff02::%awdl0/32                         link#8                          UmCI          awdl0
```

My Routing table after connecting;

```
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            link#11            UCS            46        0   utun1
default            10.0.1.1           UGScI           9        0     en0
10.0.1/24          link#11            UCS             0        0   utun1
.
.
.
.
.
10.79.115.36/32    127.0.0.1          UGSc            0        0     lo0
239.255.255.250    1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa    UHmLWI          0        4     en0
255.255.255.255/32 link#11            UCS             0        0   utun1
255.255.255.255/32 link#4             UCSI            0        0     en0

Internet6:
Destination                             Gateway                         Flags         Netif Expire
default                                 link#11                         UGCS          utun1
default                                 fe80::%utun0                    UGcI          utun0
::1                                     ::1                             UHL             lo0
.
.
.
.
ff02::%lo0/32                           ::1                             UmCI            lo0
ff02::%en0/32                           link#4                          UmCI            en0
ff02::%awdl0/32                         link#8                          UmCI          awdl0
```

So the default gateway changed from en0 to utun1

How can I configure my routing table so that I can use internet too while I am connected to the VPN?

Comment: since it is a work VPN the internet may not be supposed to work while using it. is this a expected behavior and you want to bypass that?

Comment: Yea, as it is a work VPN I'd at least ask company IT if this is what is supposed to happen. If they say "yes" you've got your answer. If they say "no" they may be able to help with the solution, or come back here with the update and we'll help figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

It's highly likely that your work's security policy requires all web traffic to go through the VPN, to ensure all your traffic is swept by their network security devices.

Contact your IT department, because if it's properly configured and secured, there's no way you'll get around it without their involvement.

Good luck.